# iMac 2011 with dual drive HDD/SSD: missing recovery mode

Tags: hard-drive, imac, startup, ssd, recovery

I upgraded my Mid-2011 21.5in iMac (running High Sierra) with the ifixit-dual drive kit (i.e. installing an SSD on top while leaving HDD and superdrive in). Everything has worked flawlessly. I don't recall how I set up the install or the cloning, though. Possibly via Time machine.
Recently, my iMac had booting problems, it got stuck at the 100% loading bar. I was able to relieve this problem in single user mode with the commands given in this [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8204994).
When trying to debug, I noticed that certain key combinations on start-up didn't work:
-safe mode, Diagnostics, recovery mode (also internet recovery), reset PRAM, choose boot device

What worked: single user mode, verbose mode

To be safe in the future, I wanted to re setup the whole system by doing a swipe and reinstalling High Sierra. I downloaded the app and the reinstall worked, but the key-combinations still don't work. I'm wondering why this is whether I set up the two drives wrongly. Terminal shows my SSD contains a Recovery partition. Find the diskutil printout below. How can I clean up everything and start from scratch? I already created a bootable USB with High Sierra, but holding option at startup does not work. Any ideas?
[image: diskutil]

Comment: What are you using for a keyboard?

Comment: wired Apple keyboard

Comment: This is not a good enough answer. I need to know exactly which Apple keyboard. I am using a Mid-2011 21.5in iMac (running High Sierra) and have several Apple keyboards. If I have your keyboard, then I can test using my machine. I have only the original internal HDD and optical drive.

Comment: A1243 german version

Comment: I tested with a A1243 English version and did not encounter any problems.

Comment: Then it's not the keyboard, thanks for your help.